# Most logical way to handle a event handler which is called twice when only one call is valid.

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, dom-events

Using prime-react's datatable. Which has an event handler "OnRowSelect". 
This event has an argument which says how the row was selected, either from the row itself, or the checkbox on the left of the table.

However when using the checkbox causes the event to fire twice.
First with "checkbox" then with "row".

I have separate method for each selection type, and need to cancel side-effects of the "row" call if the "checkbox" call is first, so as to only get the side-effects of the "Checkbox" event.

Previously with situations like this I had a timeout method which set a 'flag' which was looked for by the next call, and if the flag was raised, it didn't run. However due to race-conditions, if the "row" is called before the "Checkbox" event, it'll run and the checkbox will run.

That works, but I'm wondering if there is a more proper method?

Note that I'm not looking for some sort of denounce, as the arguments are different, and there could be some race conditions between the two calls.

Comment: In checkbox click event, do a [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Issue is, when you click on checkbox, since checkbox is inside row, the event is bubbled up. You have to stop this behavior. Using timeouts and flags are more of patch work

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Should have thought of that first, was unsure if such a solution existed as the events are created by another library rather that vanilla web-events.

Comment: even if your event is triggered via a library, you are passing it a callback. So you will have to handle there. If not, you can add a handler on row and check for target element

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use css `pointer-event:none;` on checkbox and control the checkbox by code.
When you click the checkbox, it will not trigger checkbox click event. Only tr click event.

Beware browser compatibility, it doesn't support IE10. [W3School Doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)

```js
function onRowSelectHandle(){
  document.querySelector("#myCheckBox").checked = !document.querySelector("#myCheckBox").checked;
  console.log("row selected");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
table {
  background : yellow;
  width:300px;
}
input {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}

#myCheckBox {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The pointer-events Property</h1>

<table>
  <tr onclick="onRowSelectHandle()">
    <td><input id="myCheckBox" onclick="onRowSelectHandle()" type="checkbox"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```